# Carousel slides with polymer

Tags: polymer

I'm doing some carousel using polymer framework.
But the code I used put images in slides in front of my paper-header. I mean, images in carousel slide well, but when I scroll on my web page, those images are on top of the page, so they are upon my paper-header that I used.
Here is an image of that case and the source code I used for sliding images.

How can I fix it ?
Thanks.

[Example of image on front of paper-header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yhQN.jpg)

```
<dom-module id="home-view">
  <style>
    .leTitreHome {
      font-size: 1.5em;
      color: blue;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #myslider { 
      position: static;         
      width:700px; 
      height:700px;             
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <p class="leTitreHome">Welcome</p>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <div>
      <paper-card>              
        <div class="card-content">
          <div id="myslider">
            <img src="../images/bg1.jpg" />
            <img src="../images/bg2.jpg"/>
            <img src="../images/bg3.jpg"/>
            <img src="../images/bg4.jpg"/>
          </div>
        </div>              
      </paper-card>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'home-view'

    });
  </script>
  <script>
    var imgSlider = new SimpleSlider(
      document.getElementById('myslider'),
      {
        transitionProperty: 'opacity',
        startValue: 0,
        visibleValue: 1,
        endValue: 0
      });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Please add working plunker of this question. I need it badly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be related to the `CSS` property `position: static;`.
Try changing this property and check the placement of the parent element.

Since I did not find a carousel ready, I'm also developing one:
https://github.com/discovery-tecnologia/dsc-polymer-carousel

I hope I have helped